Outlook rules trigger, email storage solution

Are all rules need to start with "after the message arrives" or "after i send the message" ?
by "after the message arrives", does it mean "when an unread email get download to outlook" ? I have a rule that mail arrived get move to another folder, I read an email on web browser, then open outlook, the account incoming by IMAP, the mail get download to outlook, the mail does not get moved, is it because of the read status ?
the ultimate problem is, I have a small mail box, I try to move all mail (inbox and sent) to a folder of another email account, if I only handle mail from that account on this computer's outlook, it would be fine, but if I read a mail on mobile outlook, or send/reply/forward mail from mobile outlook, those rules will be not trigger. Is there better way to do it?

Rules are:

messages arrives through A account move it to B folder.
after send message through A account move a copy to the C folder

Outlook settings:
uncheck "Save forwarded messages".
uncheck "Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder".

Outlook rules like "after the message arrives" and "after I send the message" are triggered when a new email is downloaded to Outlook or when an email is sent from Outlook, respectively.
The "after the message arrives" rule is triggered when a new email is downloaded to Outlook, regardless of whether it's read or unread. However, if you read an email on a web browser (or any other device) before it gets downloaded to Outlook, the email might not trigger the rule because it's marked as read on the server. This is especially true for IMAP accounts, which sync the read/unread status of emails across all devices.
As for your ultimate problem, Outlook rules only run on the computer where they're set up, and they only run while Outlook is running. So if you read or send an email from mobile Outlook, those rules won't be triggered because they're not running on your mobile device.
One possible solution is to use server-side rules if your email provider supports them. Server-side rules are stored on the email server and run regardless of which device you're using. You might want to check with your email provider to see if they support server-side rules and if so, how to set them up.
Another solution is to increase the mailbox size if possible. This would allow you to store more emails in your mailbox without having to move them to another folder.
As for your Outlook settings, unchecking "Save forwarded messages" and "Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder" means that Outlook won't automatically save a copy of forwarded messages or sent messages in the Sent Items folder. However, this shouldn't affect your rules. If you have a rule to move a copy of sent messages to the C folder, that rule should still work even if you've unchecked these settings. If it's not working, you might want to double-check the rule settings.
